# Using 2 projects with 2 different projects in workspace

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am working on a projects but have different screens. As there is more complexity I have told to create 2 projects then to marge it into 1 app.

So basically I have 2 projects lets name it as A and B. and both have 2 different storyboards.
Now I want these to projects to marge and when app fires storyboard from project A should show and there is button in project A and upon tapping it should show project B.

How can I achieve this. Can any buddy there help me..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this , but you can try this

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboardName" bundle:nil];
YourViewController *objViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: This works only when we have my 2 story boards are in same project.But here in my case I have 2 different projects with different storyboards..Any idea How can I achieve this...

Comment: i don't think this is possible because we can't access other project bundle files.

Comment: @Hemath so you mean only solution left is to copy all files from project B to A have access to its story board?

Comment: This is my personal opinion.